# Subnet Home Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, subnet

I'm looking to better organize my home network and keep computers, routers, printers, and wifi clients cleaner. I've been researching subnetting and was wondering if the attached diagram would work and all my clients can communicate across the subnets.

[image: Home Network Diagram]

I need my smart TV in the master bedroom to be able to access my movies on my media server in the basement. Will I need to setup routes or is the subnet enough?

Comment: You will need to setup routes between the subnets. Personally I would leave everything on the same network and set up the basement and first floor routers as repeaters (bridge mode) for the main router. You can use Wireless isolation for devices you want to keep separate from the main network for security.

Comment: @davidpostill, this is good advice for someone with basic consumer gear. But what if he is trying to separate broadcast traffic from chatty devices on the network?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Then he will need to master routing as well.

Comment: Currently master bedroom is setup as an access point with all computers on the same network/subnet. My concern is I may run out of IP addresses to automatically assign to devices. I have a lot of IOT devices, laptops, cell phones, etc.

Comment: So pick a subnet with more client spaces available. Like 172.16.1.1 ~ 255.255.0.0 that's just an example, you could go with much smaller client spaces like 512 etc. Also you have the channels for these three routers on non-conflicting channels right?

Comment: Yes, the routers are on non-conflicting channels.

Comment: If you want better answers for how to "clean up" or "organize" your network, you should probably share what your network is like today, and what you find to be unclean/disorganized about it, and what exactly makes a network "clean and organized" in your mind. I find a single subnet to be the cleanest, best-organized design for even a large a single family home LAN. I also use ZeroConf (a.k.a. Bonjour, mDNS, DNS-SD, Avahi) for discovery and naming, so I never have to see IP addresses, so to me there's no value in grouping devices within particular IP address ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very few good reasons for subnetting a home network, and the few that exist apply only in rare cases.

Just put one good home gateway router (NAT and DHCP server) at the head of your network, and make all your APs just transparently bridge wireless traffic onto the LAN. That way all your devices will be on the same multicast/broadcast domain so that device/service discovery protocols work, and they'll all be on the same subnet so you don't have to worry about routes.

You didn't say what your current network is like and why you consider it "unclean", but I'm guessing (from experience with a lot of other people asking questions like yours) that your network had problems because you had more than one NAT gateway, so the secondary NAT segmented part of your network from the rest, breaking discovery and connectivity in some directions.

Comment: My current network only has the main router and master bedroom router as an access point (192.168.25.x/255.255.255.0) utilizing MOCA adapters to get my network connection up to the second floor. I have had connection issues before and I wasn't able to identify if the connection issue was with the main router or the router in the master bedroom. I thought as I add the basement to the network (using MOCA again) the subnetting may help identify which router was having issues in the future.